# Data showing undefined in table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get my data into an HTML table. The JavaScript is properly detecting the data and is showing two rows in the table, which is correct. The issue is each of the fields of both rows display undefined. Not sure where to go from here.

```js
$(function() {

  var records = [];
  $.getJSON('https://v1.nocodeapi.com/devmarq/airtable/RiBnzHulmTPHkgnD?tableName=JobListings&fields=company,logo,companyDescription,role,roleDescription,location,link,dateAdded&view=AllListings', function(data) {
    $.each(data.records, function parseJSON(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.company + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.companyDescription + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.role + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roleDescription + "</td>" + "</tr>"
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="profile">
    <table id="userdata" border="2">
      <thead>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Company Description</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Role Description</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again the table is showing two rows, which is correct, but each value of the rows says undefined.

Comment: Its data.records.fields.company.

Comment: @Grumpy That doesn't solve anything. In fact, because it's so specific to that field it throws errors. Just need to get the JSON objects into the table and not read as undefined.

Comment: Please stop referring to everything as JSON this and JSON that. `data` is a JavaScript object. The fact that it came across the wire in JSON format is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pull the fields key out of the record object:

```js
$(function() {
    var records = [];

    $.getJSON('https://v1.nocodeapi.com/devmarq/airtable/RiBnzHulmTPHkgnD?tableName=JobListings&fields=company,logo,companyDescription,role,roleDescription,location,link,dateAdded&view=AllListings', function(data) {
        $.each(data.records, function parseJSON(i, { fields: f }) {
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.company + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.companyDescription + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.role + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roleDescription + "</td>" + "</tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="profile">
    <table id="userdata" border="2">
      <thead>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Company Description</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Role Description</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I changed the second argument of the `parseJSON` function from `f` to `{ fields: f }`; this uses object destructuring to grab the value of the fields entry in the object passed to the second argument and assigns it to the f variable so that the rest of the code can use that object to get their values.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain what code you changed, what it does, and how it helps the OP solve their issue. Good answers explain themselves. See [answer].

Comment: @HereticMonkey any better?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm not sure that how to answer link provides any clarity. Has it changed since you last read it?